# Dynamic checkbox and update html page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a small webpage doing the following :
1. The user selects a level then depending on the choice, there will be some options appearing as checkboxes.
2. The user can choice one or multiples options

I would like to make appear on the same page dynamically the options he or she chooses and the value associated to this. The value is stored in a mySQL database.

The first step is working but not the second one. If some one could help me ? Once the checkbox is checked or not, the page is not updating.

Here is my test code :

**Code HTML**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_class').on('change', function(){
        var _class = $(this).val();
        if(_class){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'_class='+_class,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#id_opt').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#id_opt').html('<option value="">Complete CP first</option>');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_sci').on('click change', function(){
        var _sci = $(this).val();
        if(_sci){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'ajaxDataPrice.php',
                data:'_sci='+_sci,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#id_price').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Complete CP first</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<body>    
    <form action="test_menu.php" method="POST">
        <select id="id_class" name="_class">
            <optgroup label="Primaire">
                <option value="CP">CP</option>
                <option value="CE1">CE1</option>
                <option value="CE2">CE2</option>
                <option value="CM1">CM1</option>
                <option value="CM2">CM2</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Collège">
                <option value="6ème">6ème</option>
                <option value="5ème">5ème</option>
                <option value="4ème">4ème</option>
                <option value="3ème">3ème</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>

 <input id="id_intern" type="checkbox" name="_intern" value="Yes"> Interne / Externe
 <div id="id_opt">
 </div>
 <br>

 <b>Montant à payer :</b>
 <div id="id_price">

 </div>
 <p>
```

**Code PHP**

```
if(!empty($_GET['_sci']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['_nbOpt'] > 0)
    {
        if ($_GET['_sci'] == "Yes")
            $_SESSION['_nbOpt'] += 1;
        else
            $_SESSION['_nbOpt'] -= 1;
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['_nbOpt'] == 0)
    {
        if ($_GET['_sci'] == "Yes")
            $_SESSION['_nbOpt'] += 1;
    }

    $_priceOpt = $_SESSION['_nbOpt']*5;
    $_priceTotal = 6 + $_priceOpt;

    echo 'Prix matières : 6 € <br>
            Prix matières opt : '.$_priceOpt.' € <br>
            Prix total : '.$_priceTotal.' € <br>';
            ;

}
```

Comment: `$('#id_sci').on(...)`. Where is the element with the id `id_sci`?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the browsers console for potential errors? Have you checked the browsers network tab (in developer tools) to see if it makes a request or not?

Comment: Did you receive the data `$_GET` in php?

Comment: It's hard to help if we don't get any answers to our questions/comments.

Comment: Sorry, I was out for dinner. I am going to test it asap. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: #id_sci is generated before from the class the user's selection.

Comment: while($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_exec_requete)){ 
                echo '<input id="id'.$_row['_subject'].'" name="'.$_row['_subject'].'" type="checkbox" value="Yes" onclick>'.$_row['_subFullname'].'<br>';
        }

Comment: The data is not received by ajaxDataPrice.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ajax GET for sending data as below. I think your $_GET might not received the data in php. Once changed the code clear all your browser caches and check.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_class').on('change', function(){
        var _class = $(this).val();
        if(_class){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:{'_class':_class},    //changes done here
                success:function(html){
                    $('#id_opt').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#id_opt').html('<option value="">Complete CP first</option>');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_sci').on('click change', function(){
        var _sci = $(this).val();
        if(_sci){
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'ajaxDataPrice.php',
                data:{'_sci':_sci},      //changes done here
                success:function(html){
                    $('#id_price').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Complete CP first</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tested the code and it seems that the value stored in _sci is not transmitted to ajaxDataPrice.php. When print the value of $_GET['_sci'] that gives me nothing.

Comment: Hi DroidDev, the answer works partially. The value stored in _sci is not passed to the second page. So the processing is not done. If you have an idea, it will be great. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @StéphaneMahendravasa I cant able to get you, second page in the sense `ajaxDataPrice.php` file?

Comment: yes that's it. 'ajaxDataPrice.php' and the code is above.

Comment: @StéphaneMahendravasa corrected the answer, check it. It should be like this `data:{'_sci':_sci},` and not `data:{'_sci=':_sci},`

Comment: if you don't mind, I have another issue with this code. If the checkbox are dynamically generated, the click on the checkbox is not working. Could you help me on this ?

Comment: @StéphaneMahendravasa You should probably ask another question.